# Azure SQL how to get first element in array which satisfies the condition

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with the body:

```
{
    "id": "666",
    "name": "Test",
    "lastEvents": [
        {
            "show": false,
            "eventType": "TYPE_1",
            "creationDateTime": "2020-08-16T11:59:00"
        },
        {
            "show": false,
            "eventType": "TYPE_33",
            "creationDateTime": "2020-10-14T06:11:00",
            "control": "test repaired"
        },
        {
            "show": false,
            "eventType": "TYPE_33",
            "creationDateTime": "2020-10-14T06:08:00",
            "control": "test recovered"
        }
    ],
    "_rid": "kgsjAN-JFWEDQEQWESDAD==",
    "_self": "JFWE=/docs/kgsjAN-JFWEDQEQWESDAD==/dbs/kgsjAA==/colls/kgsjAN",
    "_etag": "\"666-0000-750011b7-0000-5eec704f0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1592873510
}
```

And I would like to filter it by **first** `lastEvents.control` field. Now I am using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM root r
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT VALUE n                              
        FROM n IN r.lastEventFields                             
        WHERE CONTAINS(n.control, "recovered", true)
)
```

but this query runs through all lastEvent array. In my case, I have to check only **first element** with `control` field.
How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstand, you want to get the document which is the first element has `control` field in `lastEvents` array and it needs to contain "recovered" string.

If so, SQL can't achieve your requirement.

Workaround:

1.create UDF and loop `lastEvents` array. UDF may cost expensive, please pay attention to it. If you need, I can provide JS code.

2.add a filed in your document to check whether it meets your need on your client side before you save/update your document. If you update your document frequently, this is not a good alternative.

3.get all your documents and filter them on your client side.

Comment: No, because I don't know the exact index. It will not necessarily equal to 0.

Comment: @ArtemDanilin I updated my answer. I'm not sure understanding your meaning clearly. You can have a look.

Comment: You are correct, @Steve Zhao, there is no misunderstanding. I know about UDF and I have already tried it. In my case it will cost too much! What do you think is there a way to solve my problem without UDF? I would like to solve it by using 'native SQL'

Comment: I have tried to use operators like TOP, OFFSET, but it does not work in subqueries.

Comment: I also have tried it. Subquery doesn't support TOP, OFFSET. I have no idea to deal with it by SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not return any data for me. Here is a way to do it in a different way

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, s.show, s.eventType, s.control, s.creationDateTime
FROM c
join s IN c.lastEvents
WHERE IS_DEFINED(s.control) AND CONTAINS(s.control, "recovered", true)
```

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in my SQL. But I would like to achieve another result. Currently, my and your SQL find through all lastEvent array. But in my case, I only need the first array's element where field 'control' is define

Comment: If I understand you right, you want your query to stop iteration as soon as it finds what you are looking for. Am I correct?

Comment: I want to get the document which is the first element has control field in lastEvents array and it needs to contain "recovered" string. You can refer to the conversation with @Steve Zhao